# Select Merge not working as expected inside Enum.reduce

Tags: elixir, ecto

These are the params:

```
 %{"$select" => %{"$avg" => ["arrive_at"], "$count" => ["arrive_at"]}}
```

This is the code:

```
 Enum.reduce(select, [], fn {key, value}, fields ->
              Enum.reduce(value, fields, fn {k, v}, fields ->
                query = from p in model, select: %{}
                query = if k == "$avg" do
                  from p in query, select_merge: %{avg: avg(p.id)}
                else
                  query
                end
                IO.inspect query

                   query = if k == "$count" do
                     from p in query, select_merge: %{count: count(p.pass)}
                   else
                    query
                   end
```

First this code will run for "$avg" and this query will return

```
  #Ecto.Query<from m in Model, select: %{avg: avg(m.id)}>
```

Second time when it ran for the "$count". due to this code `query = from p in model, select: %{} .`It will reset to an empty select map again` and the result I am getting is this:

```
    #Ecto.Query<from m in Model, select: %{count: count(m.pass)}>
```

Its returning the result of the last query. What I want is this:

```
 #Ecto.Query<from h in Model, select: %{avg: avg(h.id), count: count(h.pass)}>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `query = from p in model, select: %{}` is resetting the value. You probably want to pass this query as the initial accumulator and then modify that inside the reduce function.

Comment: @Dogbert  Thanks It worked.